# rsync -- command-line for syncing from local to remote over ssh

Tags: rsync

I'm looking for some assistance please to create a proper command-line for syncing from a local machine to a remote server over ssh.

Here is a draft that is *not* working.

```
/usr/bin/rsync --dry-run --delete -arzh /Users/HOME/.0.data/ "--rsh=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/sshpass -p 'alpine' ssh -p '2222' -l root localhost" -t "cd /var/mobile/Applications/F30B1574-5979-4764-8742-7F9DB2863094/Documents/.0.data && bash --login"
```

The following command-line successfully logs in to my iphone over ssh via usb.  Id like to incorporate that working command-line into something that can be used with `rsync`, but I need some assistance in that regard.

```
/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/sshpass -p 'alpine' ssh -p '2222' -l root localhost -t "cd /var/mobile/Applications/F30B1574-5979-4764-8742-7F9DB2863094/Documents/.0.data && bash --login"
```

---

For anyone who is interested in leaning how to ssh into an iphone over usb, here is a link that discusses the method:  http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SSH_Over_USB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` must be installed on both locations.  Cydia has an `rsync` binary that installs on the iPhone.  The method of connection with `rsync` is the same as any regular ssh sever.

---

Here is a bash script solution (*includes* `--dry-run`):

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="localhost";
PORT="2222";
USER="root";
PWD="alpine";
SOURCE="/Users/HOME/Desktop/test/";
TARGET="/private/var/mobile/Applications/F30B1574-5979-4764-8742-7F9DB2863094/Documents/test";
SSHPASS="/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/sshpass";
RSYNC="/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/rsync";

$RSYNC --dry-run --progress --delete -arvzh --rsh="$SSHPASS -p $PWD ssh -p $PORT -l $USER" $SOURCE $HOST:$TARGET
```

---

For an example of how to use `rsync` in conjunction with Emacs, see the following thread:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5844/2287